# Can I stop people editing specific cells in ag-Grid?

Tags: datagrid, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I want to make only some cells in a Column editable.  I can see how I make a whole column readonly but not just some cells.
We are using ag-Grid 24 React Version together with AdapTable.

Answer (score 4):

The Column Definition property `editable` can take either a [boolean or callback function](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-grid/cell-editing/#enabling-editing-in-a-column). If you provide a callback, you can add a condition to allow cells within a column to be editable.

For example, if we wanted to allow a cell to be editable only if it contained the string `'Michael'`:

```
  const isAthleteEditable = (params) => {
    const value = params.data[params.column.getColId()];
    if (value.includes('Michael')) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };
```

See this implemented in the [following sample](https://plnkr.co/edit/YKNY1bAEhf3Xo05N).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by in ag-Grid and in AdapTable.

The AdapTable way is to provide an implementation of `isCellEditable` in [Edit Options](https://docs.adaptabletools.com/docs/adaptable-options/edit-options) (which you can then style through either the `readOnlyCellStyle` or `editableCellStyle` properties in [User Interface Options](https://docs.adaptabletools.com/docs/adaptable-options/user-interface-options) if required).

See [this demo](https://demo.adaptabletools.com/edit/aggridreadonlycellsdemo) for more info.